# Can not perform a login programmatically to a website

Tags: java, apache, http, cookies, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have this code, witch compiles and runs without a problem:

```
package isitup;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.cookie.Cookie;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.client.CookieStore;
import org.apache.http.client.params.ClientPNames;
import org.apache.http.cookie.CookieOrigin;
import org.apache.http.cookie.CookieSpec;
import org.apache.http.cookie.CookieSpecFactory;
import org.apache.http.cookie.MalformedCookieException;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCookieStore;
import org.apache.http.impl.cookie.BrowserCompatSpec;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;

public class Test {
     public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {

            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.cashialize.com/wp-login.php");

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            System.out.println("Login form get: " + response.getStatusLine());
            if (entity != null) {
                EntityUtils.consume(entity);
            }
            System.out.println("Initial set of cookies:");
            List<Cookie> cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
            if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("None");
            } else {
                for (Cookie cooky : cookies) {
                    System.out.println("- " + cooky.toString());
                }
            }

            HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("http://www.cashialize.com/wp-login.php");

            List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("log", "test"));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pwd", "test"));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rememberme", "forever"));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("redirect_to", "http://www.articlepub.com/wp-admin/"));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("testcookie", "1"));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("wp-submit", "Log In"));


            httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));

            response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
            entity = response.getEntity();

            System.out.println("Login form get: " + response.getStatusLine());
            if (entity != null) {
                EntityUtils.consume(entity);
            }

            System.out.println("Post logon cookies:");
            cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
            if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("None");
            } else {
                for (Cookie cooky : cookies) {
                    CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();

            // Bind custom cookie store to the local context
            httpclient.setCookieStore(cookieStore);
            CookieSpecFactory csf = new CookieSpecFactory() {
                public CookieSpec newInstance(HttpParams params) {
                    return new BrowserCompatSpec() {
                        @Override
                        public void validate(Cookie cookie, CookieOrigin origin)
                                throws MalformedCookieException {
                            // allow all cookies
                        }
                    };
                }
            };
            httpclient.getCookieSpecs().register("easy", csf);
            httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, "easy");
                }
            }




            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.articlepub.com/wp-admin/profile.php");
            response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
            entity = response.getEntity();
           // System.out.println("Page Contents: " + EntityUtils.toString(entity));


            System.out.println("Login form get: " + response.getStatusLine());
            if (entity != null) {
                EntityUtils.consume(entity);
            }

            System.out.println("Post get cookies:");
            cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
            if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("None");
            } else {
                for (Cookie cooky : cookies) {
                    System.out.println("- " + cooky.toString());
                }
            }


            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);

        }

    }

}
```

The problem is that I can't get the user logged in. I'm pretty sure that I'm missing something in the cookies setting, but I'm inable to spot it, as it is one of my first login tries.

The console output also seems good - the only problem is that I can't spot the cookies. Here it is:

```
Login form get: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Initial set of cookies:
None
Login form get: HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Post logon cookies:
None
Login form get: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Post get cookies:
None
```

Please, help me with this nightmare! I'm pretty sure that I'm missing something really small, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking you need to configure a cookie store on the client before you execute.  You can possibly also configure an HttpContext with a cookie manager.

Try looking at this document: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.2.x/tutorial/html/statemgmt.html